# Application Security

Tags: security, permissions, lost-phone, application-manager

If an android device is stolen by someone who is one of expert android users, in such case, we're not sure that how he can manipulate the stolen android device.

In such case, sometimes its suspicious for me. Email apps and banking apps are one of confidential apps. If any apps are locked by application locker or application inbuilt lock, can it be considered that an offender can get access any locked apps at certain scenario? Under certain scenario, an offender can be a hacker, Android Developer or any expert android used?

Please look and clarify it.

Regards
GNS

Answer (score 1):

Basically, physical access means full access. There is nothing to protect against physical attacks.

Regarding your questions:

1. Yes, an offender can get access to any app installed on the device, simply uninstalling the application locker or disabling it using tools as simple as the [Android Debugging Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) can yield full user data access.

1.1. Application built-in locks may prevent an offender using an app, but the data is still in his hands.

2. An offender is an *offender*. There is no need to figure out if he is a hacker, developer or expert user, the borders are unclear and debatable.

**Advice:**

Utilize [Full Disk Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/) (preferably with a custom, long and secure password) to protect against offenders copying data and analyzing it offline. Offline data analysis renders remote wiping useless.

The worst thing that could happen: The offender clones sensitive apps/apps containing sensitive data or apps that hold monetary value to another (maybe even virtual) device. You can't do anything but reset all passwords and hope the offender didn't buy anything expensive on your account.